# can't figure out routing in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm doing my first steps in asp.net mvc trying to develop web api.

I have the following routing function:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "cdApiDefault",
        url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{token}/{mid}/{id}",
        defaults: new {
            token = UrlParameter.Optional,
            mid = UrlParameter.Optional,
            id =  RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and the following controller:

```
namespace cdapi.Controllers
{
    public class PostsController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/posts
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "GET_value1", "GET_value2" };
        }

        // GET api/posts/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
        }

        // POST api/posts
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/posts/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/posts/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }

        public String GetTest(String token, String mid)
        {
            return token + " - " + mid;
        }
    }
}
```

the following call

> hxxp://localhost:52628/api/posts/5

(in my browser) yields some result, i.e., the function GET is being called and return a value.

However, when I try

> hxxp://localhost:52628/api/posts/GetTest/MyTestToken/myTestMid

comes back with *'the resource can not be found'* error message.

I thought that the **{Action}** should contain the function to call and that the **'token'** and **'mid'** should contain the values I specify. What do I do wrong?

Comment: I'm not writing this as an answer yet because I'm not sure if this is spelling error in your question or the cause of the problem, but in case of ASP.NET Web API you should be using `MapHttpRoute` not `MapRoute` - please check.

Answer (score 0):

ApiControllers work differently than regular MVC Controllers. Here, method names (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) represent HTTP VERBS, not url fragment. In your first call,

```
/api/posts/5
```

this invokes `Get(int)`.

To do routing like you want, switch to standard MVC by inheriting from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` instead of `System.Web.Http.ApiController` and modify your methods to return `ActionResult`